# JGraphT - Dijkstra shortest path/minimal cost path

Tags: jgrapht

I'm trying to use JGraphT for some simulation over graphs.

It has the Dijkstra algorithm, and i'm not so sure that if I run the Dijkstra for a weighted graph it will consider weights.

I'm trying to get the minimum weight path from vertex a to vertex b

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As is custom for SO, please include a [MRE]. It's important to include some code to (i) exemplify what you are looking for and (ii) to show some minimal effort.